# Doesn't `array.some()` find the first true value and then not execute the remaining iterations? The following snippet shows otherwise

Tags: javascript

I was informed that `array.some()` unlike `array.forEach()` finds the first true value that matches the expression and then does not execute the remaining iterations.

The following executed as expected.

```
let result = [23, 357, 23, 34, 6, 37].some( function (value) {
    return value % 2 === 0;
});

console.log(result);
```

However, when tweaked a little and run in the node interactive terminal, I found that it does NOT stop at the first true expression, as previously thought.

```
[23, 357, 23, 34, 6, 37].some( function (value) {
    console.log(value % 2 === 0);
    return value % 2 === 0;
});
// gives me `false, false, false, true, true`
```

Is this normal?

Comment: You agree that `undefined` is not a truthy expression, correct?

Comment: add return and then console

Comment: "removing the actual return statement" is one hell of a tweak.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans haha...

Comment: Use `console.log(value, value % 2 === 0);` instead.

Comment: In order to improve my questions. Can somebody please explain why this particular question received 3 downvotes? It's not really helpful to say something doesn't work and then not provide a solution.

Comment: I didn't downvote but my guess is actively removing the return statement from the function then wondering why it behaves unexpectedly has something to do with it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will stop iteration till first return is `true`.

Without no return, which equivalent to return of `undefined`, so it would iterate through all the array

So you missed the condition to `return` in this debugging snippet

```js
[23, 357, 23, 34, 6, 37].some(function(value) {
  console.log('DEBUG:', value % 2 === 0);
  return value % 2 === 0
});
```

Comment: Can anybody explain why I get `false, false, false, true, true` when I run exactly the same code directly in the node terminal?

Comment: @Grateful The final `true` is the returned value of `some`, when the array does have at least one element fulfilled the condition, as in the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) (Syntax > Return value). I updated the answer for you to debug more clearly

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your time and effort.